# How to update chrome app to manifest 2

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest

My chrome extension is one of those that when you click it, all it does is open up a URL. It used to work fine with `web_url`, but `web_url` isn't working with manifest version `2`.
Here is my current extension manifest:

```
"name": "PTD",
"version": "2.7.8",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Pokemon Tower Defense 1 and 2!",
"icons": {"128": "128.png"},
"default_locale": "en",
"app": {
   "urls": ["http://gamecorneronline.com/ptd.html"],
   "launch": {
      "web_url": "http://gamecorneronline.com/ptd.html"
    },
   "permissions": ["unlimitedStorage","notifications"]
}
```

Could you provide any help?

Comment: Did you take a look at http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html ?

Comment: btw where did you see that `web_url` doesn't work with manifest version 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Thanks for the help anyways:

```
{
  "name": "PTD1/PTD2",
  "description": "Play both PTD1 and PTD2!",
  "version": "3.2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "urls": [
      "http://example.com/",
    ],
    "launch": {
      "web_url": "http://example.com/"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "notifications"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What was the exact problem and how did you fixed it? Please expand you're solution by adding details. This might help others in the future. Also, consider marking one of the answers as 'accepted'.

Comment: Well, it wasn't working. Thanks for reminding me to mark the answer though.
I don't get what was wrong...the only difference between this and my old one, is formatting. Anyway, I couldn't find the answer anywhere(easily) on the net, so decided to share it. I checked the manifest page, and nothing worked. Eventually, I found a google question thing, and it said for chromebooks, how to add a quick link. Anyway, issue solved.

Comment: Spotted! In the wrong manifest, `permissions` are *under* `app` property, whereas in the working version, they are declared *beside* to `app` property. Also, the non-working version has `default_locale` property, but I doubt this is the issue.